# Some problems in rigorously showing $\inf\{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S=\{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\inf S=\frac{1}{2}$ by observation.

I am trying to rigorously show the the infimum of $S$ indeed $\frac{1}{2}$

First, $\frac{1}{2}$ is the lower bound for $S$ by observation.

Now, remains to show for all $\epsilon>0$, there exist $x\in S$ such that $x<\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon$.

In other words, $1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}<0.5+\epsilon$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Re-arrange we have

$$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{(-1)^n+n\epsilon}{n}$$

If $n$ is odd:

$$
n<-2+2n\epsilon\\
\frac{2}{2\epsilon -1}<n
$$

Now if I check this conclusion by letting $\epsilon=0.1$, the LHS is negative value and $n$ can takes the smallest odd natural number $1$. And this is not the case that

$$
1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}<0.5+\epsilon\\
2=1-\frac{(-1)^1}{1}<0.5+0.1
$$

**Where does it go wrong? and how to rigorously show this question?**

Comment: If you divide an inequality by a negative number the inequality gets reversed.

Comment: By the way, you may note that $\frac{1}{2}$ is also $\min S$. If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ has a minimal value, then $\min A=\inf A$ (an easy-to-check fact). So you can directly conclude $\inf S=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When going from $n<-2+2n\epsilon$ to $\frac{2}{2\epsilon -1}<n$ you divide by $2\epsilon - 1$. For small values of $\epsilon>0$ that quantity is negative, and thus dividing by it changes the direction of the inequality. What you should have is
$$\frac{2}{2\epsilon -1}>n$$
and as you note, the LHS can be negative, so this inequality will no hold for any $n$. But this inequality was derived from assuming $n$ is odd, so you can conclude that the $n$ you are looking for is even. Indeed, note that
$$S'=\left\{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N} \text{ and $n$ is odd}\right\}
=\left\{2,1+\frac{1}{3}, 1+\frac{1}{5}, \ldots \right\}$$ and $\inf S' \neq \frac{1}{2}$.